# Android Popup Menu fill parent

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I try set my popup menu in way to fill hole item on grid. Currently it look like on attached first picture and the next one is effect which I would like to have.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.PopupMenu);

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctw, view);

    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Remove");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "Block");

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show();
}
```

Could you please point me to right direction to achieve effect from project?

Comment: try with `PopupWindow` instead of `PopupMenu`, it has rich api

Answer (score 3):

> Demo App for your requirment by using PopupWindow. [**Preview**](http://d2flqmogg10inr.cloudfront.net/assets/videos/0kkkhc87video-20170406-200515-11272439311491490986.mp4)

You can add list in it or customize it according to your needs.
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean isClicked = true;
    PopupWindow popUpWindow;
    RelativeLayout relative;
    ImageView btnClickHere;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
        popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
        popUpWindow.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_design, null));
        popUpWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.textViewa).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PopItemClicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btnClickHere = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnClickHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isClicked) {
                    isClicked = false;
                    popUpWindow.setHeight(relative.getHeight());
                    popUpWindow.setWidth(relative.getWidth());
                    popUpWindow.showAsDropDown(relative, 0, -relative.getHeight());
                } else {
                    isClicked = true;
                    popUpWindow.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sohailzahid.testapp.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="150dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="150dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**popup_design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F93567">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Block"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVsiewa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Add to friends"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViesw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Remove"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   popup.getWindow().getAttributes().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
   popup.getWindow().getAttributes().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: PopupMenu is from import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu and there is not present method getWindow()