# Android : How to make Popup Menu to have same width as its anchor?

Tags: android, popup

I want to make Popup Menu which does similar operation like spinner where I need select one item from its dropdown popup.

**I am not able to achieve Popup Menu of same width of its Anchor.**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257164/android-popup-menu-fill-parent/43259125#43259125

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I tried with popup window but was unable to get desired results so am just changing my mind to use default spinners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using custom view with popup menu. Its better you can use spinner and spinner its provide own dropdown list window you can able to set design whatever you want.

Comment: Yes you right, it would be better to use default spinner.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need a spinner or popup menu.

I had the exact same problem and couldn't find a good answer after searching for a while.
I ended up passing the Anchor View to the `PopupWindow's` constructor.

```
public TestPopupWindow(Context context, View anchorView) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context; 
        this.anchorView = anchorView;
        createView();
}
```

And setting the `width` during the view inflation.

```
private void createView() {
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.popup_window_layout, null); 
        this.setWidth(anchorView.getWidth());
        setContentView(view);
}
```

Simple and works for me