# Android. How to show popup window directly above button

Tags: java, android, scrollview, popupwindow

I need to show popup window directly above button. My button is placed inside scroll view, and popup always shown below button. Here is my code:

```
  private void showPopup(View view, String text) {
    if (infoPopup == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_credit_request_passport, null);
        TextView tvPopupText = popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv_popup_text);
        tvPopupText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tvPopupText.setText(text);
        FrameLayout flBackground = popupView.findViewById(R.id.fl_background);
        flBackground.setBackground(new BubbleDrawable(getContext(), R.color.azure, 16, 16, 8));

        infoPopup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        infoPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        infoPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        infoPopup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP, (int) view.getX(), (int) view.getY());

    } else {
        dismissInfoPopup();
    }
}
```

But it is not work. Please hep me.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257164/android-popup-menu-fill-parent/43259125#43259125

Comment: what is the view you are passing in the function? use the getLocationOnScreen() method of View and pass an int array to get the Location in the screen, then use those in the showAtLocation() method, pass the Button in this function...

Comment: And give an example of what you are trying to achive here, design or something

Answer (score 2):

Change **Gravity to Top** and reset your coordinates according to your requirement.

```
infoPopup.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP, 0, (int) view.getY());
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but now popup is shown at top of screen , not above button

Comment: i told you..you have to set coordinates according to requirement...i edited my answer you can try this..

Comment: I place popup above button, but the direction of popup is to the top, is it possible change direction to the bottom ?

Comment: at which exact position you want to show your popUp?.
.for top of the view(button) use Gravity.Top and for bottom of the view(button) use Gravity.Bottom. And by using  (int) view.getX() and  (int) view.getY() you can get exact coordinates of your view(button) and can show your popup at any specific position.

Comment: make sure you are passing your button to Parameter "view".. call showPopup(button,"your text")

Answer (score 1):

When you have to show the popup, find out the location of the button in the screen, then use the `showAtLocation()` method as **Prachi** Said using `Gravity.TOP` and the `x,y coordinates` of the button on screen...