# Method showAtLocation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, methods, menu, popup

I am attempting to create a popup menu that comes from a button at the bottom right corner of the screen. The issue is that the menu would need to be displayed above the button. Ive botched together some code from [Android. How to show popup window directly above button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422647/android-how-to-show-popup-window-directly-above-button). However, the `showAtLocation` method does not resolve. Another issue that I believe is related to this is that the activity crashes ever since I added my `onMenuItemClick()` switch statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) and more code can be found at my [Github](https://github.com/dgtutv/Workout-App)

--edit---

So it turns out that `showAtLocation` only works for popup windows, however I am using a popup menu. So the question becomes, ho wdo you make a popup display above a button rather than below?

**WorkoutsCreater.java**:

```
package com.example.workoutapp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WorkoutsCreater extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workouts_creater);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Workout Creater");                                      //change text at top of screen accordingly
        Button btn=findViewById(R.id.BtnNew);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(WorkoutsCreater.this, v);                                    //display menu when button clicked
               popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(WorkoutsCreater.this);
               popup.inflate(R.menu.workout_new_popup_menu);
               popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP, 0, (int) v.getY());               //show popup above button
           }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item: " +item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {                                                                                             //testing which button is pressed in menu
            case R.id.RepBased:
                System.out.println("Rep Based");
                return true;
            case R.id.RunBased:
                System.out.println("Run Based");
                return true;
            case R.id.TimeBased:
                System.out.println("Time Based");
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**workout_new_popup_menu.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/RepBased"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_workouts"
        android:title="Rep Based" />
    <item android:id="@+id/RunBased"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_run_black"
        android:title="Run Based" />
    <item android:id="@+id/TimeBased"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_time_based"
        android:title="Time Based" />
</menu>
```

activity_workouts_creater.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WorkoutsCreater">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NameWorkoutTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name of Workout:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/NameWorkoutInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/NameWorkoutInput"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/NameWorkoutInput" />

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/NameWorkoutInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/NameWorkoutTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showAtLocation()` is a `PopupWindow` method, not a `PopupMenu` method. 
The code you copied uses it on `PopupWindow` as well.

You can read more about `PopupWindow` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow?hl=en) and about the specific method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow?hl=en#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Would it be possible to convert a popup menu into a popup window? If not is there a way to display the menu above the button rather than below? I can't find anything on it anywhere

Comment: Maybe try playing around with the gravity attribute? You can read more about it through the below link-

https://www.tutorialride.com/android/android-gravity.htm

Again, you can also read about gravity and the setGravity() method in the PopupMenu docs-
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/PopupMenu#setGravity(int)

Try exploring more of the documentation. If you're going to find anything, that's usually the best place.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out and have a re read of the android guide.

Comment: So I found `v.setOnTouchListener(popup.getDragToOpenListener());` Which should at least keep the menu on the screen. However apparently the cause fro rthe crashing is not gone. As it crashes and I can't test the program. I know it is something to do with the popup as it started crashing when I added the popup code. Would you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: You need to include the error log in your question for people to be able to help with errors.

Answer (score 0):

`v.setOnTouchListener(popup.getDragToOpenListener());` fixes the popup issue and the crashing was caused by using the wrong button type. Turns out you cannot use floating action buttons with popup menus